# How to debug this bug caused by type traits?

Tags: c++, sqlite, memory, type-traits, bulletphysics

I encountered a really strange bug in my application. It is a video game that uses [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/) among other libraries.

After implementing a SQLite interface, collision detections got messed up. The players falls through the terrain, or collides with invisible objects. To me it looks like a wrong memory access. The database functionality works fine though.

I could already narrow down the issue. The SQLite interface uses type traits which are provided by the different storeable types. When commenting out all trait specializations, collisions work fine.

How can I find the reason of this bug? Please let me know if any other information could be useful for solving the problem, so that I can include that into the question.

Update: This is the code that I need to comment for proper collisions. The storable type is `Person`.

*type/person/type.h*

```
#pragma once
struct Person
{
    float Height, Mass;
    // ...
};
```

*type/person/trait.h*

```
#pragma once
#include "type.h"
#include "manager/data/manager.h"
using namespace std;

template <>
struct ManagerDataTrait<Person>
{
    static const unordered_map<string, string> Fields;
    static void Serialize(Person *Instance, ManagerData::Serialization *Data)
    {
        Data->FLOAT("height", Instance->Height);
        Data->FLOAT("mass",   Instance->Mass);
    }
    static void Deserialize(Person *Instance, ManagerData::Deserialization *Data)
    {
        Instance->Height = Data->FLOAT("height");
        Instance->Mass   = Data->FLOAT("mass");
    }
};
```

*type/person/general.cpp*

```
#include "type.h"
#include "trait.h"
using namespace std;

const unordered_map<string, string> ManagerDataTrait<Person>::Fields = []{
    unordered_map<string, string> fields;
    fields.insert(std::make_pair("height", "FLOAT"));
    fields.insert(std::make_pair("mass", "FLOAT"));
    return fields;
}();
```

Comment: Add the specializations back in one at a time. Whenever it fails, analyze that specific thing you just added?

Comment: you could provide a sample of the code that you need to comment in order for you application to work and code that uses that code.

Comment: @Mat Good idea. I my case I had already set up a single specialization for testing. When added, the bug occurs and otherwise not.

Comment: @bolov I updated the question to include that code.

Comment: The specializatiin should be visible adjacent to the type.  UB occurs if one unit sees it and another does not.

Comment: @Yakk I included the specialization along with the general trait in the SQLite manager, and collisions do work again! Could you please explain what *"UB"* is and how it can break unrelated components like collisions while the component using the trait works fine? If you would write an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: UB is undefined behaviour.  If a `template` is used in two contexts on a particukar type, and in one it can see the specialization and in another it cannot, the resulting program is ill formed and no diagnostic message is required, if I remember correctly.  On my phone so do not have the time nor interface to do a proper answer: I encourage you (or anyone else) to track down citations about that, or just write it up prettier.  :)

Comment: @Yakk One more question, is there a include strategy so that I don't need to include specializations in the general trait file? I would like to not have to drop a line there for every new specialization.

Comment: @danijar yes. Put it in the `Person` file.

Comment: @Yakk That's what I did before and what caused the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user Yakk answered my question in the comments.

> The specialization should be visible adjacent to the type. Undefined behavior occurs
>   if one unit sees it and another does not.